# UITableView Delegate is not called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my VC there  is one `UITableView` and with one `UIlabel`. As i have done all thing by code and there is nothing in the `Storyboard`.

**Issue :**

1. If i didn't reload the `UITable` then not any `UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate` is called.
2. If i reload the `UITable` like I have done in my below code the `cellForRow` is not called.

I have done below code work.

```
    import UIKit


protocol DataVCProtocol
{
    func addNewVC(Index : Int)
}


class DataVC: UIViewController,  UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var delegate:DataVCProtocol?

    var tblData : UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        super.viewDidAppear(true)

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.tblData = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 20 , height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height), style: UITableViewStyle.plain)
        self.tblData.delegate = self
        self.tblData.dataSource = self
        self.tblData.register(TblDataCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "dataCell")

        self.tblData.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        self.tblData.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        self.view.addSubview(self.tblData)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK:- TableView Datasource
    // MARK:-

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat{
        return 60
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return 10
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let dataCell : TblDataCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "dataCell") as! TblDataCell

        dataCell.lblDataText.text = String("data cell #\(indexPath.row)")

        return dataCell
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

        delegate?.addNewVC(Index: indexPath.row)
    }


}
```

**see the Right cell**

[image]

Comment: You forgot to add the ```tableView``` as subview to the controller's view.

Comment: Remove "public" keyword then try.

Comment: @danypata nice catch

Comment: You are not using addsubview for add table view

Comment: My code is worked properly after adding Subview. Now i again do the same code in other VC and i found the same problem, I edited my code, Please have a look.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I will post a generic answer for your problem that I think many devs will have when they start working on iOS and to be honest I had it way more times that I should have:

So whenever the delegate methods are not called for a `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`, usually there are 3 main reasons for that.

1.The most common, the delegate is not set, so it's nil, in this case no method will be called on the delegate (obviously).

2.The `numberOfRowsInSection` returns 0 or the `numberOfSections` returns 0, in this case these methods will be called, but no other methods will be called, this is a good way to debug the problem.

3.The tableView or the collectionView is not added as a subview to the main controller, this is happening when the devs prefer code instead of storyboards or xibs. In this case the delegate is set (not nil) but no method from delegate is called, another tip for this is, you don't see the table view default dividers.

**UPDATE(thx to Kevin comment)**

4.Check what you return in all your delegate methods because some return values cause other methods to be skipped

Comment: I'd like to add my personal failure. I had implemented all available delegate and datasource methods, assigned both properties and still didn't get some callbacks. Turned out I returned nil in willSelectRow... causing didSelectRow.... to never get called. So 4. Check what you return in all your delegate methods because some return values cause other methods to be skipped.

Comment: @kevin That's a good point. I've updated the answer. Might help other people in the future.

Comment: Holy Hole in a Doughnut, caught out by #1 after X-years of app development.

Comment: @Mississippi I think everybody had this problem at least once in their dev life, thus number 1 :).

Comment: So, I've been developing iOS for 10 years now. And, I'd added a UITableView to a MkMapView and added a table view in code. I'd set my delegates, data and source and added all the relevant methods. None appeared to be firing. Talk about frustration. I must have added hundreds of table views in my time and this got me. The comment above about ensuring ALL delegate methods fire was VERY true in my case. I'd copied/pasted a whole section of standard methods from a saved standard script. And in that I was returning ZERO from here, numberOfSectionsInTableView, stopped other delegates from firing.

Answer (score -2):

you have to alloc memory to tableview.

Kindly do bellow thing.

```
var tblMenu: UITableView  =   UITableView()

tblMenu.frame         =   CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 200);        tblMenu.delegate      =   self
tblMenu.dataSource    =   self
tblMenu.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

You missed this part

```
self.view.addSubview(tblMenu)
```

Comment: He's 'init'-ing the tableview in the ```viewDidLoad``` method.